# Can Albanian PM Rama go ahead with the elections without President Meta's support?

Tags: election, albania

A brief summary of the current situation in Albania, from the BBC:

> Albanian President Ilir Meta has cancelled local elections after months of anti-government protests.
>
> Mr Meta said the political situation in Albania would not allow for fair elections, scheduled for 30 June.
>
> ...
>
> Mr Rama insists elections will go ahead as planned. For months now, Mr Rama has been at odds with the president - a former coalition ally.
>
> <sub>Albania president cancels local elections. (2019). Retrieved from https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-48571159</sub>

Can Rama, the Albanian Prime Minister, ignore the President and go ahead with the elections? Or is Meta's support required for the elections to be legal?